# OWASP ZAP Form-based Authentication does not send Autorization HTTP header in active scan

Tags: authentication, owasp, zap

I am using **OWASP ZAP to scan my API**. I have followed [all steps to set up the OAuth2 authentication](https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/desktop/start/features/authentication/). But when I start an active scan, the **requests still do not contain the bearer token**. The Authorization header is missing.

The screenshots of my setup are bellow.

I went through the list of steps to set up the Forms Based Authentication:

[image]

Defined the user

[image]

Set the Session Management to HTTP Authentication:

[image]

There's probably some missing piece in my puzzle, any advice is welcome.

Answer (score 1):

You've selected the wrong type of Session Management. It would be `HTTP Authentication Session Management` if you were doing Basic or Digest auth.

For your scenario you'd need to select [`Script-based`](https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/desktop/start/features/sessionmanagement/#sbsm) and setup something like: https://github.com/zaproxy/community-scripts/blob/main/session/Juice%20Shop%20Session%20Management.js

Other options like env vars are outlined here:
https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/authentication/handling-auth-yourself/